# Force datatype when importing from excel

Tags: c#, sql, excel, sql-server-2012

I am using the following code to read data from excel and populate a datatable.
Later I use the datatable to populate a Database table.

This works fine until a column is not of type "general" and the cell values are of multiple formats.

```
| Column 1 |
------------
| 28.756%  |
| 14.654%  |
| *        |
```

Where Column 1 is of datatype percentage and values are only shown to 3 decimal places but actually do contain more data.

When columns are like the above, the imported data is truncated to 3 decimal places and we lose any precision that was not displayed on the screen i.e. 12.3544123% becomes 12.354%.

I have found a solution to this is to open the excel file, select all the cells and change the data type to general. But I dont want the users or my script to do this as some of the excel files i am using are very large and opening and saving can take a considerable amount of time.

Is there a way I can adapt the code below to force the "general" datatype as it reads the values into the datatable?

```
String FilePath = "Code to get file path";
String SheetName = "Code to get sheet name";
String SheetRange = "Code to get sheet range";

SourceConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO'";

OleDbConnection SourceConnection = new OleDbConnection(SourceConnectionString);

String strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" + SheetName + "$" + SheetRange + "]";

OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, SourceConnection);

DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();

OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter(myCommand);

myDataAdaptor.Fill(myDataTable);
```

Comment: Try casting everything as a string in your query.  I have no idea if you can do that with excel, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Yes that would be an option, but this is not just for one data source, but for potentially hundreds. I cant explicitly convert anything in the select statement as it will then stop working for other data sources.